# add 3rd party link (with script) to menu item

Tags: menus, scripts

I was given a code to add to a button to make a pop up for calendaring (booking).

I can figure out how to add this to the body of the page, but I'd like to add it to a menu item.

here is my code:

```
<a href="https://hopeandwellness.clientsecure.me" class="spwidget-button" data-spwidget-scope-id="6c77380d-c2a0-4190-a51e-77cad166320f" data-spwidget-scope-uri="hopeandwellness" data-spwidget-application-id="7c72cb9f9a9b913654bb89d6c7b4e71a77911b30192051da35384b4d0c6d505b" data-spwidget-scope-global data-spwidget-autobind>Book Now</a><script src="https://widget-cdn.simplepractice.com/assets/integration-1.0.js"></script>
```

Placing this in the body works great...it adds a button that when clicked, opens a pop-up.

If I put this code in a menu item for a custom link, the link just disappears when I save the menu.

I also tried just adding the link to the URL field, and the class to the "css classes (optional)" field, but didn't know where I would put the script or data fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add those links with "Custom links". I have tried your link and it works as expected, it shows on my menu and open the popup.

[image: Custom link]